# How to reload data in UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Since `UITableView` is in `UIViewController`, I made a class that conforms `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and attaches it to the table view in `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` like below.

delegate for table view in UIViewTableController:

```
class TableViewController: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {       
    var data

    // where should I do this task and how can i reload data after task? 
    data = asyncFuncToGetData() 

    // this is not working
    override init() {
        data = asyncFuncToGetData() 
    }

    func tableView() {
        // uses variable data
    }
}
```

UIViewController:

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!
    let delegate = TableViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainTableView.dataSource = delegate
        mainTableView.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

I have to fetch data from server because table needs it. So where should I do that? This can be done easily when `UITableViewController` conforms `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, but I do not want that way.

Comment: fetch data in  viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch your data in **ViewDidLoad** and then feed it to your delegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainTableView.dataSource = delegate
    mainTableView.delegate = delegate

       asynFuncToGetData( { newData in
             //Assign New Data to your delegate class's data
             self.delegate.data = newData
             //Call Reload data on tableView's instance
             self.delegate.tableView()
       }  
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I forgot that `deletage` is just a object. Thank you